# Solving inequation with a solution set from another inequation

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Given that the solution set of inequation

$$ax ^ 2-bx-1>0$$
is $-1/2<x<-1/3$, I want to calculate the solution set of inequation

$$x ^ 2-bx-a\geq 0.$$

I have used the following code, but is there a faster and better way to solve this problem?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
sol = First@Solve[{-1/2 - 1/3 == b/a, 1/6 == -1/a}, {a, b}]
(* {a -> -6, b -> 5} *)

Reduce[x^2 - b x - a >= 0, x] /. sol
(* x ∈ Reals && (x <= 2 || x >= 3) *)
```

Comment: From where do you obtain `{-1/2 - 1/3 == b/a, 1/6 == -1/a}`?

Comment: Obviously, these two numbers are the two roots of the equationax ^ 2-bx-1=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we find the set of `a` and `b` for which the solution of `a*x ^ 2-b*x-1>0` is  `x > -1/2 && x < -1/3`.

```
cond = Resolve[ForAll[x, x > -1/2 && x < -1/3, a*x^2 - b*x - 1 > 0] && 
ForAll[x, x >= -1/3, a*x^2 - b*x - 1 <= 0] && 
ForAll[x, x <= -1/2, a*x^2 - b*x - 1 <= 0], Reals]
```

> A long output, its `LeafCount` equals `5460`

Now

```
Reduce[x^2 - b*x - a >= 0 && cond, x, Reals]
```

> `b == 5 && a == -6 && (x <= 2 || x >= 3)`

finishes the work.

Edit. `ForAll` instead of `Exists` in `cond = Resolve[ForAll[x, x > -1/2 && x < -1/3, a*x^2 - b*x - 1 > 0] &&  Exists[x, x >= -1/3, a*x^2 - b*x - 1 <= 0] &&  Exists[x, x <= -1/2, a*x^2 - b*x - 1 <= 0], Reals]`